# How to update database when itemselected on listbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

I need a help.

I need to know how i can update my database when listbox item is selected, and what i want to update is the quantity.

That is the design that i have:

[image]

What i want is:
When i select field "Narnia" i want to decrease the quantity on my database.

I already tried that by myself but when i select an item, that decrease all of quantitys, not only on "Narnia"

```
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Livrosescola SET Quantidade = Quantidade - 1 ", myConnection)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a criterion to specify in your query that you wan modify just the row of ""Narnia" or an element selected :

So your query must be something like :

```
 cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Livrosescola SET Quantidade = Quantidade - 1 
 where NomeLivro like '*" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "*'", myConnection)
```

Comment: Operator & is not defined for String "Livrosescola =" and type "DataRowView" got that error.

Comment: Try to change code to :NameOfyourColumne='" & listbox.selectedItem & "'

Comment: cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Livrosescola SET Quantidade = Quantidade - 1 Where NomeLivro ='%" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "%'", myConnection)

Comment: Try to change query to : Where NomeLivro  like '*" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "*' ", myConnection)    >> use *  instead of  %

Comment: Glad to hear that :)